# Problem with font-family in .css file using Atom

Tags: html, css, fonts, atom-editor, linux-mint

I'm using Atom 1.45.0 x64 on Linux Mint19.3 Cinnamon to learn basics of web development (I'm following a course of html5, CSS and JavaScript).
I have 2 problems (probably related to each other):

1. whenever I type the 'font-family' command in my .CSS file the only input suggestions I get are the ones you can see in the screenshot I uploded here. No way to specify other fonts;
2. whenever I choose one of the available options, the fonts in my html page won't change (and it's not because of typos, bad linking between html and css files, etc).

[fonts currently available on my Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZnct.png)

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem and I can't figure it out on my own because I'm not an advanced user of Linux systems. I've also installed the 'fonts' package on Atom but that hasn't solved the problem.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem affects Atom. Try to change from `font-family` to `font-style` and declare the value. So instead of doing `font-family: italic` try typing `font-style: italic;`

Found similar problem here, even if it's using Windows 10: https://discuss.atom.io/t/why-cant-i-change-the-font-problem-solved-the-answer-is-inside/21086

Comment if can't resolve.

Comment: Thank you very much, now the font changes are shown on my html pages (I edited the style.less file). Btw, is there a way to have atom showing more options than just those six?

Comment: Unfortunately, Atom teams are working on this "issue" but for the moment there aren't any solution.

Comment: I may try to download some extensions but I've heard you've just did it, so for the moment let's hope for an update!

Comment: Mmm I see. Let's hope for the best then. Thank you again for your help!